# How to use Vue.js in Hexo (static site generator)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, static-site, hexo

I would like to use [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) for parts of a template in my [hexo](https://hexo.io/) theme.
How can I compile my .vue-files to be used in my template (in dev and production)?
I’m not talking about server side rendering, vue.js should run on the client side (but would also be an option).

Comment: I am having the same issue. I called in vue via cdn but the Hexo variables are not avail to vue

Comment: I think we'd have to use webpack or browserify to compile the .vue files, which is not included by default in hexo. This site uses hexo and vue so could be an example of how to go about achieving this: https://github.com/briangonzalez/briangonzalez.org/blob/master/themes/briangonzalez.org/source/js/app.js

Answer (score -2):

vue.js website built with hexo.
You can check the source code:
https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org

Comment: It does not use vue.js at all.